# GoogleMaps API: How to remove multiple markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a function that pins marker in Google Map. This is how it looks:

```
// Look to draw marker in various coordinates. Pseudo code...
for(var i = 1; i <= noOfCoordinates; i++){

   var lat = latitude[i];
   var long = longitude[i];

   drawMarker(lat, long);

};

var drawMarker = function(lat, long){
// code to draw marker

marker.setMap(map);

};
```

But I also have a function to remove those markers

```
for(var i = 1; i <= noOfCoordinates; i++){

   removeMarker(null);

};

var removeMarker = function(map){
// code to draw marker

marker.setMap(map);

};
```

drawmarker(); pins/draws marker in google map but removeMarker(); does not remove all markers from the google map, it only removes last one.

I want to remove all marker associated with it, that was drawn from drawMarker(); function. Remove = hide, not delete.

how can I fix this?

Comment: Keep references to all the markers, call `.setMap(null)` on each one.

Comment: What do you mean by references? and how to keep?

Answer (score 0):

> Keep references to all the markers, call .setMap(null) on each one

geocodezip suggests like this:

```
markers = []; // <-- global variable

for(var i = 1; i <= noOfCoordinates; i++){

   var lat = latitude[i];
   var long = longitude[i];

   var marker = drawMarker(lat, long);
   markers[i].push(marker);
};

var drawMarker = function(lat, long){
// code to draw marker

  marker.setMap(map);
  return marker;
};
```

---

```
for(var i = 1; i <= noOfCoordinates; i++){

   markers[i].setMap(null);

};
```

Comment: I did that but it does not delete the markers. I also get error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setMap' of undefined

Comment: Also I get this error: InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama ... js?key={{...... there is some key here....}}:34 InvalidValueError:

Comment: The variable `markers` have to be global variable

Comment: I made it global. It still does not remove markers.